# SQL bulk update [specific scenario]

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I want to update multiple fields in the same table for many items with a single SQL command.
For example, I have an array:

```js
  const itemsToUpdate = [
{id:23, fieldToUpdate1:true,fieldToUpdate2:"..."},
{id:54, fieldToUpdate1:false,fieldToUpdate2:"..."},
{id:50, fieldToUpdate1:false,fieldToUpdate2:"..."}
]
```

I want to create a single SQL command that updates the fieldToUpdate1 and fieldToUpdate2 of each item in the array with its corresponding id.
PS: i am going to use typeORM with RAW queries.